# Javascript - primitive string implicit conversion to object

Tags: javascript, string, implicit-conversion

I will reference to [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) docs about String object.

> JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and call the method or perform the property lookup.

Good example of such situation would be accessing length property:

```
let word = "Hello";
word.length;
```

I have understood that what happens in this situation is:

```
let word = "Hello";
String(word).length;
```

But after trying some [benchmarks](https://jsbench.me/jbk4318xvu/1) it's clear for me that `word.length` is much faster than `String(word).length`. It seems that implicit conversion is something completely different than `String(word)`, much faster. I cannot find any info about how this implicit conversion works, but it might be helpful to know in some optimization problems.

Comment: You're creating a String object, as the quote says.  Getting the length of that is quicker than creating another string object from the value of the first, and then getting the length of that.  The performance tests are not the same.

Comment: In first case do we make String object somehow basing on a primitive one? Of course we also do as in the 2nd case.

Comment: They are 2 different things.  `String("Hello").length` and `String(String("Hello")).length`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is probably time to parse and the fact that inner JS string object (that is actually C++) works faster then creating extra interface to interact with string on high JS level...
So it's all about optimisation
There is good article about it (https://dev.to/promhize/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascripts-implicit-coercion-e23).